# MaxMind IP Lookup Speed with Python API

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, maxmind

I'm building a script to process web server logs, and I'm trying to incorporate MaxMinds's IP dataset (http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/) into the script in order to get the country the hit is coming from.

Currently, my script works fine when I just have it extract the information I want, however when I try to add IP lookup's it slows down - a lot - by about 1800%.  So, I'm curious if this has something to do with my code or if there is a way I can speed this up.

For example, when I run the following code extracting date and ip address, for this experiment it took about 6.5 seconds.

```
extractedData = []

for log in logList:
    ip = log[-1]
    date = log[0]
    dateIP = [date, ip]
    extractedData.append(dateIP)
```

When I add pyGeoIP and try to incorporate the country code it slows down.  The following code took 2 mintues and 7seonds to run.

```
extractedData = []

gi = pygeoip.GeoIP('/path/to/GeoIP.dat') 

for log in logList:
    ip = log[-1]
    country = gi.country_name_by_addr(ip)
    date = log[0]
    dateCountry = [date, country]
    extractedData.append(dateCountry)
```

So, is there a way to speed this up since this look up will slow to process down too much.

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're doing many queries, you should load the database into memory. As it stands, you're repeatedly reading from the disk, which is painfully slow.

Exchange this line:

```
gi = pygeoip.GeoIP('/path/to/GeoIP.dat')
```

to this:

```
gi = pygeoip.GeoIP('/path/to/GeoIP.dat', pygeoip.MEMORY_CACHE)
```

Comment: That brought it down to 28 seconds, so significant improvement.

Comment: @cloud36 There will always be some overhead doing the lookups. If you absolutely need better performance, you may want to check what's the bottleneck in your code (potentially through system performance monitoring) and optimize for it (multithreading or multiprocessing for CPU bottleneck and using RAID, a SSD or simply reading files into ram if it's the disk)

Comment: You could also use the [C extension](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GeoIP) with [libGeoIP](https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-c), which would like provide a considerable speed boost. That said, pygeoip is more pythonic and easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but tried both Python and PHP on a CentOS box. Running 3M ip-addresses through a Python script took 19.5 minutes. Applying the MEMORY_CACHE optimization brought it down to 8 minutes. Running the same data through a PHP script took 2-2/3 minutes.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about the "MEMORY_CACHE" optimization?

Comment: As mentioned above:

Exchange this line:
<code>
gi = pygeoip.GeoIP('/path/to/GeoIP.dat') 
</code>
to this:
<code>
gi = pygeoip.GeoIP('/path/to/GeoIP.dat', pygeoip.MEMORY_CACHE)
</code>